# Puzzling performance of index scan. Why is scanning index slow even though result set is small and indexed

Tags: performance, sap-ase

I have large table ir_data (150GB) which contains data for different dates (column val_date). I need to know if a given date is available in the ir_data at various points in my application.

```
select distinct(val_date) from ir_data
```

I the following experiment ir_data contains 29 different values for val_date.

---

SETUP 1

I expected an index on ir_data (val_date, key_id, other_colum) to help finding the 29 values quickly. In fact this takes **more than 5 minutes**:

> Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 29, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 343.96,
>   SQL query: 343.958, Reading results: 0.002

I always expected an index to be a tree where the nodes are stored in a tree structure, e.g. like this

```
val_date -> key_id   -> other_column -> data-nodes

1.1.2017 -> 0-50     -> A            -> (1.1.2017, 0, Automobile), (1.1.2017, 2, Amsterdam)
                     -> B-E          -> (1.1.2017, 12, Batman)
         -> 51-100   -> A            -> ...
                        X
         -> 666-1000 -> A
                     -> B-C
                     -> E
2.1.2017 -> ...
```

Based on this structure getting the 29 different val_dates should be very quick.

**Question**: Why does this take so long???

Sub-question: Is there a way to fix this without creating another table?

---

SETUP 2

I created another index which only contains val_date. It takes about the same amount of time.

---

Query-Plan:

```
    The type of query is SELECT.

2 operator(s) under root

   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 2)
   |
   |   |GROUP SORTED Operator (VA = 1)
   |   |Distinct
   |   |
   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |  ir_data
   |   |   |  Index : ir_data_idx1 <-- this is the index containing only val_date.
   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |  Positioning at index start.
   |   |   |  Index contains all needed columns. Base table will not be read.
   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |  With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
```

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yes, I should have mentioned that. Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is very large as well as your index.
As you can see in the plan, the engine performs an index scan.
This operation will be lengthy because it will scan your *entire* index for distinct values.

As a first step, You could try `update index statistics` on the index, though, i don't really think it'll help.

If it's a one time manual operation, i guess you'll be satisfied with the 5 min operation.

If it's a query executed by your application then you have 2 choices i can think of:

1. As you said in the question - normalize the table by creating additional table for the dates and use FK.
2. Create a `precomputed result set`. This is a materialized view - the results are stored like a regular table (as opposed to a view where only its definition is stored).
   It will automatically refresh the results in the view and values will be retrieved fast.
   **Important:** like indexes, it will have an impact on the performance of Insert, Update...
   It can look like:

   ```
   create precomputed result set prs_ir_data
   immediate refresh
   as
   select distinct val_date
   from ir_data
   ```

You can read [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1572/html/new_features/new_features31.htm) and [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/commands31.htm) about precomputed result set

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what kind of data structure they use? I find it hard to understand why it should be neccessary to scan over the whole index just to find the top level attribute of the search structure.

Comment: The foreign key idea is very good, I did not think about that.

Comment: Glad i could help. I'm not sure about the internal structure of sybases indexes, but surely it's some kind of b-tree to allow fast searches and insertions

Comment: I found a way to speed this up! Its actually quite remarkable, see here for more details: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan

Comment: But, you're working on sybase-ase - it doesn't exists there.

Answer (score 0):

A [recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781958/how-does-a-recursive-correlated-expression-speed-up-distinct-queries?noredirect=1#comment72813916_42781958) speeds up this query considerably, i.e. very few distinct values in a large table. The problem is that index seeking during search for distinct values is not implemented currently. Here is a [link to the approach](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan).