# How does a recursive correlated expression speed up distinct queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I found [this post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1013407.aspx) about speeding up distinct queries:

Super-fast DISTINCT using a recursive CTE:

```
USE     tempdb;
GO
DROP    TABLE dbo.Test;
GO
CREATE  TABLE 
        dbo.Test 
        (
        data            INTEGER NOT NULL,
        );
GO
CREATE  CLUSTERED INDEX c ON dbo.Test (data);
GO
-- Lots of duplicated values
INSERT  dbo.Test WITH (TABLOCK)
        (data)
SELECT  TOP (5000000)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) / 117329
FROM    master.sys.columns C1,
        master.sys.columns C2,
        master.sys.columns C3;
GO



SET     STATISTICS TIME ON;

-- 1591ms CPU
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        data
FROM    dbo.Test;
```

-- 15ms CPU

```
WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
        SELECT  data = MIN(T.data)
        FROM    dbo.Test T
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  R.data
        FROM    (
                -- A cunning way to use TOP in the recursive part of a CTE Smile
                SELECT  T.data,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.data)
                FROM    dbo.Test T
                JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                        ON  R.data < T.data
                ) R
        WHERE   R.rn = 1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    RecursiveCTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0);

SET     STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
DROP    TABLE dbo.Test;
```

The recursive CTE is 100 times more efficient :-) This kind of speedup would be extremely valuable for my current project, but I am not sure in which cases this approach is beneficial.

To be honest: I don't get why this speeds up the query that much and why the database cannot do this optimization itself. Can you explain how this works and why it is so effective?

---

Edit: I see a similar effect on sybase, so this approach does not seem to be valid for sql-server only.

Sub-question: is the recursive CTE useful for other data base systems as well?

Comment: The answer was from [Paul White](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white).The main reason it was fast is he knows the data in the table and he knows how to get past [optimizer limitations](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/tags/Internals/default.aspx) and code efficiently

Comment: regarding why database can't optimize all scenarios like the one you stated above.Below is quote from Itzik Ben-Gan stating the same..`SQL Server’s optimizer is truly a marvel when you think of what this software component can achieve. But it’s a fact that it doesn’t have all possible optimization rules encoded within it. Two, the optimizer has to limit the amount of time spent on optimiza-tion; otherwise, it could spend a much longer time optimizing a query than the amount of time the optimization shaves off from the run time of the query. `

Comment: The situation could be as absurd as producing a plan in a matter of several dozen milliseconds without going over all possible plans and getting a run time of only seconds, but producing all possible plans in hopes of shav-ing off a couple of seconds might take a year or even several. You can see that, for practical reasons, the optimizer needs to limit the time spent on optimization.

Comment: Based on factors like the sizes of the tables involved in the query, SQL Server calculates two values: one is a cost considered good enough for the query, and the other is the maximum amount of time to spend on optimization before stopping. If either threshold is reached, optimization stops, and SQL Server uses the best plan found at that point

Comment: @TheGameiswar If I want the optimizer to spend a lot of time optimizing, is there a way to tell it to do so?

Comment: check out this link :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/is-it-possible-to-give-the-optimizer-more-or-all-time-it-needs

Comment: In this case, I think I agree with @Beginner.  Why doesn't the optimizer use the clustered index for the `distinct`?  It should be able to scan the distinct values in the index . . . this does not seem like a "special purpose" optimization.  It seems like a sane use of indexes for `distinct` and `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, SQL Server's optimizer is not smart enough, i.e. it doesn't implement this kind of optimization method. It was requested in 2011, but rejected. See [Implement Index Skip Scan](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan) Connect item. Maybe it will be implemented in some future version.

Comment: Please, do not blindly apply examples of successful optimizations on whatever case you have!!!  Better do thorough analysis of what is slow (and significantly contributing to bad performance) and waht could be done for improving the situation. If it then comes down to "the optimizer is considering a plan as 'good enough' that is far from optimal, it is time for looking at how to circumvent that deficiency. Employing a CTE might then work, as it effectively splits the optimization effort: one part focussing on the CTE and another using that result with optimizing the full query.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . It is interesting that skip-scan was rejected.  It is one of the nice optimizations that Oracle offers.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, regarding - "a cost considered good enough for the query" and  "maximum amount of time to spend on optimization before stopping" , I seriously doubt the existent of any of these concepts, more likely an hard-coded number of execution plans is generated and the one with lowest cost is chosen.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz:I think,there must be a time limit and in that,time limit,the one with lowest plan would be choosen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, regarding "Why doesn't the optimizer use the clustered index ..." - yes it does, traversing the data through the index leafs in an ordered fashion and outputs any new value it finds,. It makes a lot of sense for a large number  of distinct values . for a small number  of distinct values an optimization would be to skip the repeated values in the leafs. This could be done by traversing **up** the index, look for a range that contains the next distinct value, and then dive **down** again, repeatedly.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - It doesn't make much sense. for a one time query the optimization time it not a crucial factor and for a repeated query it would be wiser to take the time and produce a good execution plan that would be cached for future executions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paul White explained this "trick" in great detail in his post [Performance Tuning the Whole Query Plan](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan) under **Finding the Distinct Values** section.

> Why the database cannot do this optimization itself?
>
> Is the recursive CTE useful for other data base systems as well?

Optimizer is not perfect and it doesn't implement all possible techniques. People asked Microsoft to implement it. See this Connect item [Implement Index Skip Scan](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan). It was closed as Won't Fix, but that doesn't mean that it won't be addressed in the future. Other DBMSes may have implemented it (Connect item says that Oracle implements this optimization). If this kind of optimization is implemented in the DBMS engine, then this "trick" is not needed and optimizer would choose optimal method of calculating the result based on available statistics.

> I don't get why this speeds up the query that much.
>
> I am not sure in which cases this approach is beneficial

The simple `DISTINCT` query scans the whole index. "Scans" means that it reads each and every page of the index from the disk and aggregates the values in memory (or tempdb) to get a list of distinct values.

If you know that the table has a lot of rows, but only few different distinct values, then reading all these repeating values is a waste of time. Recursive CTE forces the server to seek an index for the first distinct value, then seek an index for the second value and so on. "Seek" means that server uses binary search in the index to find the value. Usually one seek requires reading of only few pages from disk. "Index" is a balanced tree.

If the table has only few distinct values it is faster to seek few times, than read all pages of the index. On the other hand, if there are a lot of distinct values then it would be faster to read all pages sequentially, than seeking for each consecutive value. This should give you an idea in what cases this approach is beneficial.

Obviously, if the table is small, it is faster to scan it. Only when the table becomes "large enough" you start seeing the difference in performance.

---

There is a related question on dba.se: [Is it possible to get seek based parallel plan for distinct/group by?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/96364/57105)

Comment: The optimization require here is "skipping" repeated values while "Skip scan" is intended for skipping the first order key of a composite index. It is actually not relevant to this post.

Comment: Actually there is nothing to aggregate in this DISTINCT query. Logically, a value can be output as soon it is being recognized as a new distinct value, by comparing it to the last known distinct value - which is the only information that is needed to be saved during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Noteable point when above script is run in my machine.

Disctinct query= clustered scan is 94%

Recursive query=clustered scan is 14%

This is the main reason

Disctinct query

CPU time = 920 ms,  elapsed time = 211 ms.

Recursive query

CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 64 ms.

In this example may be recursive option seem good.

but in real world example getting disctinct result using recursive may not be good idea.

Therefore you cannot say, "**Super-fast DISTINCT using a recursive CTE:**"