# SQL Server sampling large volume of data per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Im using SQL Server 2016, and have a very large table containing millions of rows of data from different sources at irregular intervals over several years. The table cannot be altered, typical data looks like this -

```
Reading_ID    Source    Date                  Reading
==========    ======    ====                  =======
1             1         2023/01/01 00:04:00   7
2             1         2023/01/01 00:10:00   3
3             2         2023/01/01 00:15:00   8
4             1         2023/01/01 01:00:00   2
5             2         2023/01/01 01:03:00   15
```

The table has CONSTRAINT [PK_DATA_READINGS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Source] ASC, [Date] ASC). The SOURCE can be any number, its not fixed or known in advance. New sources can start at any time.

What I want to do is specify a date range and an interval in hours, then just get 1 reading from each source every X hours. i.e. in the above row 2 wouldn't be returned as its too close to row 1

I've tried something like the following -

```
DECLARE @Start_Date DATETIME = '2023/01/01 00:00:00',
        @End_Date DATETIME = '2023/02/01 00:00:00',
        @Interval_Hours = 4

;WITH HOURLY_DATA AS (
     SELECT d.Source, 
            d.Date, 
            d.Reading,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Source, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Start_Date, d.DATE) / @Interval_Hours ORDER BY d.SOURCE, d.DATE) AS SOURCE_HOUR_ROW
     FROM data_readings d
     WHERE d.DATE BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
)
SELECT h.Source,
       h.Date,
       h.Reading
FROM HOURLY_DATA h
WHERE h.SOURCE_HOUR_ROW = 1
```

But its still very slow to execute, sometimes taking 5 minutes or more to complete. I would like a faster way to get this data. I've looked at the Explain Plan, but cant see an obvious solution.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: How many distinct Source are there? Is there a table that has the distinct values?

Comment: A list of distinct `Source` valules would help massively, as then you could do a correlated join on `Source, Date`. Without that you have to scan the whole table.

Comment: The SOURCE can be any number, its not fixed or known in advance. New sources can start at any time.

Comment: And typically how many sources are there? It is still possible to get a distinct list of sources [efficiently from an index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42853242/73226) with leading column `Source` but not worth the hassle if there are loads of little sources with a few rows each

Comment: WHERE d.DATE BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date , it seems like you need an index on Date column and you're set to go?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's possible to also get such a list using an indexed view, see below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The slowness is caused by the volume of data in the CTE.
I found this solution which works faster [How to sample records by time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168881/how-to-sample-records-by-time)

Answer (score 2):

You say the `Source` column has no table that it correlates to. This significantly worsens performance options, as it means you have no way of skipping through your `(Source, Date)` index by date.

Ideally you would have a table containing a list of possible `Source` values using a foreign-key relationship. There is no reason why you couldn't update this dynamically.

However, you can hack it with an indexed view.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vAllSources
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  dr.Source,
  COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.data_readings dr
GROUP BY
  dr.Source;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UX_AllSources ON AllSources (Source);
```

The server will efficiently maintain this index based off the original table.

Then you can do a simple join. Use the `NOEXPAND` hint to force it to use the index.

```sql
DECLARE @Start_Date DATETIME = '20230101 00:00:00',
        @End_Date DATETIME = '20230201 00:00:00',
        @Interval_Hours = 4;

WITH HOURLY_DATA AS (
    SELECT
      d.Source, 
      d.Date, 
      d.Reading,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Source, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Start_Date, d.DATE) / @Interval_Hours ORDER BY d.DATE) AS SOURCE_HOUR_ROW
    FROM AllSources s WITH (NOEXPAND)
    JOIN data_readings d
      ON s.Source = d.Source
     AND d.DATE BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
)
SELECT h.Source,
       h.Date,
       h.Reading
FROM HOURLY_DATA h
WHERE h.SOURCE_HOUR_ROW = 1;
```

Note that `BETWEEN` on date values is generally not recommended, as it implies `>= AND <=`. You are far better of using a half-open interval:

```sql
     AND d.DATE >= @Start_Date AND d.DATE < @End_Date
```

You should also use [non-ambiguous date formats.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/)